# Python prints memory location instead of list elements

Tags: python, list, class, memory, printing

Python prints memory location instead of list.
My code:

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def show_card(self):
        print(self.value, self.suit)

    def get_value(self):
        if self.value > 10:
            return 10
        return int(self.value)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for suit in ["♣", "♦", "♥", "♠"]:
            for value in range(2, 15):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, value))
        return self.cards

    def shuffle_deck(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self.cards

Deck().build()
deck = Deck().shuffle_deck()
print(deck)
```

The problem is when I append "Card" object to "cards" list.
How could I print "cards" list elements instead of memory locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved through `__repr__` magic method. Add this method:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'{self.value} {self.suit}'
```

into your `Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a repr function to the card class

```
class Card:
    # your implementation
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({self.value},{self.suit})'
```